# ImportError: allauth needs to be added to INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I've been following this tutorial on the django for apis book by William Vincent. I need to use django-allauth. I've installed it in my venv, added it to installed apps and done all the necessary things according to the installation instructions on the [Documentation](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/quickstart.html). On running `python manage.py migrate` , the error comes back as `ImportError: allauth needs to be added to INSTALLED_APPS.`

This is my settings.py in the relevant areas

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",

    # 3rd party libraries
    "rest_framework",
    "corsheaders",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount",
    "dj_rest_auth",
    "dj_rest_auth.registration",

    # Local
    "accounts",
    "posts",
]
......

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
            ],
        },
    },
]
....

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
]
```

I appreciate the help in advance.

I tried checking the documentation, checked all the commas were put in the appropriate place. Looked for similar situations on reddit and stackoverflow but coudln't find anything along that line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its a problem with the latest version of allauth, dj_rest_auth is not compatible yet.
Change your allauth version on your pipfile to  0.54.0

django-allauth = "==0.54.0"

Comment: Yeah, I did and it worked. Some folks also mentioned it on GitHub. Cheers Mate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

The cause may be "django-allauth".
It may be resolved by changing from 0.55.0 to 0.54.0.

Answer (score 1):

Happened the same after upgrading *allauth* from 0.54 to 0.58.2 .

I had to upgrade dj_rest_auth, to version 5.0.2. Now it's working again for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a try in imports section in this file site-

```
packages\dj_rest_auth\registration\serializers.py
```

Delete it and you will realize that the library is broken.